# Could someone please explain the outcome / idea of this expression in Typescript to me?

Tags: typescript, expression

Can anyone explain this expression (in detail) to me? What does it do? What do the `!!` mean?

```js
const foo = useState(props.index ? !!props.formikContext.values.foobar?.[props.index]?.foofoo: false);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Forget the useState function, just focus on the expression.

```
let result = props.index ? !!props.formikContext.values.foobar?. 
[props.index]?.foofoo: false;
```

Means if props.index is not null/0/false/undefined, result equals

```
!!props.formikContext.values.foobar?.[props.index]?.foofoo.
```

!  can convert data to boolean type and invert it.

!!  can convert data to Boolean type but no invert.

```
let a = 0;
let b = !a;
let c = !!a;
console.log(b, c);  // b equal true, c equal false
```

? use in typescript means this property is optional.

```
let data: {a?: string, b: string} = {b: "abc"};
// now a is optional ,if we want get length of a.
let len = data.a?.length;
```